# Determining whether a relation disrupts freeness of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we examine a group with presentation $G = \langle a, b, c ~\vert~ c^2 \rangle$. It's my suspicion that the subgroup $\langle a, b \rangle$ is free, since the relation in the presentation does not "touch" these generators. However, in more complicated scenarios, this may be difficult to determine. For example, if $G= \langle a,b,c,d ~\vert~ acd^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle$, is the subgroup $\langle a, b \rangle$ free? Again, I suspect yes, though I am not sure how to prove it, if it is even true.

Are there conditions on the relations that can help easily determine whether a subset of generators generates a free subgroup under the relations?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiheitssatz

Answer (score 3):

The first example is a free product of the free group on $\langle a,b \rangle$ and the cyclic group $\langle c \rangle$ of order $2$.

In the second example, you just eliminate the generator $d$, and see that $G$ is the free group on $a,b,c$.